# Pointers vs Global Variables in terms or RAM on a PIC

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, ram, pic

I have just finished my code using global variables. I know using global variables is frowned upon so I was going to use pointers instead.

So initially my function was `void time (void)` with the global variables being called within the function. 
After i changed the program to `void time (unsigned char *xp, unsigned char *yp, unsigned char *zp, unsigned char *ap)`

I tested the RAM usage for both (PIC16F877A) and to my surprise the ram usage went up after i used the pointers. These pointers will be deleted after the function is no longer being called and i have used them correctly (that is not an issue). Can someone please explain to me why this is? 
I was under the influence Pointers make the efficiency of your program better.

Additional information (All the 4 variables were global variables before they were turned into pointers).

People have asked me to post my code so here it goes (this one has pointers in it and i am using a PIC16F877A)

```
`void time (unsigned char *time1p, unsigned char *time2p, unsigned char *time3p, unsigned char *finishp){
unsigned char i, j=0;
unsigned char timer [] = {"Time has expired"};    //Memory saver
 if (*time1p == 0 && *time2p == 0 && *time3p == 0)   //if all the time is 0 finish the sequence
                               *finishp = 1;

                           if (*time1p != 0)              //Checking to see if the first digit is NOT at 0
                              *time1p = *time1p - 1;             //  subtract time 1 by 1
                           else {*time2p = *time2p - 1;            //When time1 is 0
                                *time1p = 9;}                    //Time1 going back to it's original value

                           if (*time2p == 0 && *time1p == 0){        //if time1 and time2 are 0s
                           LCD_cursor(14,0);
                           LCD_display_value(*time2p);               //Display its value
                          Delay_ms(200);                          //Use the delay


                           if (*time3p != 0){                        //The minute value (time3)
                              *time2p = 5;                             //60 SECONDS
                              *time3p = *time3p - 1;
                              *time1p = 9;  }  }                      //Put time 1 to its original value


                                                                   //Puting the correct numbers in order
                LCD_cursor(15,0);
                LCD_display_value(*time1p);
                LCD_cursor(14,0);
                LCD_display_value(*time2p);
                LCD_cursor(13,0);
                LCD_putch(':');
                LCD_cursor(12,0);
                LCD_display_value(*time3p);
                Delay_ms(300);
        /*Memory saver*/
                        if (*finishp == 1){
                        LCD_clear();
                              while (timer[j] > 0x00)
                              {
                               LCD_putch(timer[j]); //Print the string
                                j=j+1;
                                }
                        for (i=0; i < 10; i++){
                        i=0;                   }
                                        }

   ////////////End of memory saver

}         //end of time function`
```

Comment: In which aspects is a pointer the opposite of a global variable? And pointer **to what**? Your question is far from being clear. Which PIC? PIC32? PIC16/18? dsPIC? PIC24?

Comment: how/how much did you reserve space for dynamic allocation?

Comment: @user3528438: Hopefully OP did not use dynamic memory allocation on a PIC16 I presume).

Comment: @Olaf Well, then we need to see some code.

Comment: I have stated PIC16f877A, 
Pointers aren't the opposite to a global variable, i haven't said that at all. 
@user3528438 I am using MikroC and it does this automatically. 

There isn't anything wrong with my code, i asked a really simple question. Why do pointers take up more memory than global variables on PIC16F877A?

Comment: Point is "pointer" is not the opposite than "global variable". (You did not say this explicitly, but your question's text very well implies it.) So the question is not answerable!

Comment: It depends on so many things even things like how you measure memory usage. Some platforms allocates dynamic memory pool at system configuration time, so the memory pool reserved for dynamic allocation is counted as memory usage in a similar way as global variables, because they are both statically allocated before runtime. However the actually usage of the memory pool depends on how your program runs.

Comment: Like, your system configuration tool detects a call to malloc then it allocates a 64K memory pool for it. Then even if malloc only uses a small portion of it, the space reserved for the memory pool won't be accessible to anything else hence counted as "memory usage".

Comment: @user3528438: 64k pool? No. The mentioned PIC has 368 bytes of RAM....

Comment: @Olaf I have just re-read my original question and can't seem to find where I have said pointers are the opposite of global variables. None the less if i have indirectly mislead you, i do apologise. That was not my intention.

Comment: You should read more about embedded programming, especially on such ancient and restricted architectures like PIC; your code is in general very inefficient for this architecture, not just RAM-wise. Read (and understand - no offence) the datasheet, mostly the instruction set and memory architecture. It is very different from a "normal" CPU or modern MCU like ARM or MSP430.

Comment: `unsigned char timer [] = {"Time has expired"};` -> `const unsigned char ...` **might** help. But that particular PIC has a problem accessing variables in ROM, so it depends very much on the toolchain how this is solved. Best solution might(!) be to have a global pool of strings (possibly using attributes or similar) and just pass an "index" into this pool to a `print` function. This could be automated by some generated code (I generally recommend Python for such jobs).

Comment: Either way, if you **really** need optimised code (be it speed, power consumption or memory), you have to know your target and toolchain very well. If in doubt check the Assembler code and map-file. The PIC is an ungrateful target for C code if you have to worry about all this.

Comment: To be *very honest* : Your current implementation combines the disadvantages of global variables with the disadvantages of using pointers ;) Better return on global vars - This will make your program much easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

On small and very small embedded devices, *predictability* of memory consumption is much more important than *clean-looking code* and should definitely have precedence. Statically allocated memory gives you this predictability. The program either runs or doesn't, but won't crash after 2 hours because of exhausted memory. That is one reason why on small devices you shouldn't really use dynamic allocation.

The other reason is that dynamic memory allocation does not come for free - Memory management needs some memory for its own inner workings, and a *pointer* normally has the biggest size of all scalar type of an architecture.

Storing a char as a static variable on a PIC or AVR costs you: 1 byte

Storing a char on the heap costs you: 1 byte for the char, 2 bytes for the pointer.

Go figure ;)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Using pointers does not imply dynamic memory allocation, nor does it not. Your calculation makes assumptions which are also not given. A local pointer need not take additional memory, if thre has to be memory reserved for locals anyway.

Comment: I think it answers what the OP *wanted to ask*. But I'm with you he could have asked *better*

Comment: Very nice answer, you have explained it very nicely. 
I feel like catch 22, if i don't use pointers i have 40 global variables but if i do use pointers i use up too much memory. I have opted for the pointer option and have only used up 50% of the ROM. 
Thanks a lot mr @tofro , i appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, you are a clairvoyant! The que4stion cannot be asked; there is just not enough information given. Also, your initial statement is plain wrong. Readability/maintainability is often a major factor. Even more when it comesd to safety-relevant programming. And neither static nor dynamic allocation does not contradict that.

Comment: @Olaf: I would perfectly be with you if we'd be talking about anything at least the size of a good old Commodore 64. We aren't. Instead we talk about a system that has 384 *bytes* of RAM. In my opinion, *anything* is allowed that saves from there. I do agree you can mess up a lot of code in 14K flash, though. So readability/maintainability should be second.

Comment: @Olaf I have uploaded my code for this program, it is in a function so i just copied the function. I have used pointers in the uploaded version

Comment: @Badprogrammer: As I suspected: There is no dynamic (i.e. heap-based) memory allocation as this answer presumes, just passing local variables.

Comment: yes Mr @Olaf i designed it that way to make sure it was efficient and the variable would be deleted once the function was no longer called and hence saving memory. Any thoughts on a possible answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

> So initially my function was void time (void) with the global variables being called within the function. After i changed the program to void time (unsigned char *xp, unsigned char *yp, unsigned char *zp, unsigned char *ap)

This is why you saw your RAM usage go up; you created four *new* objects of type `unsigned char *` where you didn't have them before.  Storage for the function arguments will be allocated at function entry and released at function exit.

Globals are frowned upon in general, but sometimes you can't avoid using them.  In your particular situation, it's probably better to stick with globals and document the hell out of everything.

Comment: It depends on the call-chain with the most local variables used. Using additional local variables does not necessarily result in more memory usage. A modern toolchain might very well store local variables in global space, not on a stack.

Comment: That does not really disprove what John has said in the context of the citation - Wherever the compiler puts them, unsigned char* will use twice the memory than unsigned char. And "something to point to" must always be there. This counts even more if the pointer is totally unnecessary (like in this example)